# Php call to member function query() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using mysqli for a function, and I'm getting an error, `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 46` I've tried different things, but I just get different errors, what am I doing wrong and where is my error?

Code lines 45-51:

```
function fetch($query) {
    $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
    $result =  $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    return $result;
    $sql->free();

}
```

Here's my previous attempt and error : `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 46 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 47 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 46 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/u250000297/public_html/forum/system/db.php on line 47`

Code, lines 45-51:

```
 function fetch($query) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    return $row;
    mysqli_free_result($row);

}
```

Connection:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
    mysqli_select_db( $mysqli,$this->database );
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

}

Comment: Where and how do you call your `fetch` function?

Comment: In my mail.php file  `$mail = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "_mail WHERE id = '$mail_id'");` and `$account = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email' AND lpip = '$lpip'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to define `$mysqli` as global or pass it as an argument.
After a return, no statement will be executed (mysqli_free).

Global:

```
function fetch($query) {
    global $mysqli;

    $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
    $result =  $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);


    return $result;


}
```

Parameter (and even better):

```
function fetch($myslqi, $query) {

    $sql = $mysqli->query($query);
    $result =  $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);


    return $result;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Points to debug are

1) Is the connection to the database getting established?

2) Are your query strings correct?

Call to a member function query() on a non-object and Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli means that the $mysqli is null or isn't initialized properly. To get more information check the mysql error logs.

Comment: Yes, the connection to the database is established, and I'm pretty sure my strings are correct